# How i can do for know what i have to do i this type of cases: root?

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

I receive that message when I want install or try to don know that was installed, after it's here :

```
apt-get install linux-generic -(the error)-
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What do I have to do in this case, and how I can run a message automatically on my desktop if it's hacked?

P.S. I need a secure port, or a few secure number ports.

Answer (score 0):

Run your installation command with `sudo`. The error is basically saying are you `root`. It needs to create a lock file, which is not possible if you aren't `root`

```
sudo apt-get install [package name]
```

Comment: thank you so much you are right, in this case i run to install without sudo and give me that error denied installation, to installations only enter run with sudo ever, thank you. Case solved.